# Recursive on Gray Code

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gray-code

I have been curious since working on gray code that how can I write recursive function to calculate the integer that appear in position m of n-bit (as show in the link that I provide) like 3-bit Gray Code at position 5 is 7.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Binary-reflected_Gray_code_construction.svg

Figure: The Reflect and Prefix Method.

**General Information**

Gray Code is an ordering of the binary numeral system such that two successive values differ in only one bit (binary digit). For example, gray code of 3 digits (and its decimal) are listed as follows:

000 = 0,
001 = 1,
011 = 3,
010 = 2, and vice versa which is simple binary number.

Comment: There are 10 kinds of people: those who don't understand binary, those who do, and those who prefer Gray code. :-)

Comment: Isn't the mapping $$n\mapsto n \operatorname{XOR} (n \operatorname{DIV}2)?$$ Instead of integer (valued) division by $2$ you can shift the bits to the left by one position. In your 3-bit example $0\mapsto 0 \operatorname{XOR} 0=0$, $\ldots,$
$2\mapsto 2 \operatorname{XOR} 1=3$, $\ldots,$
$5\mapsto 5 \operatorname{XOR} 2=7$, $\ldots,$
$7\mapsto 7 \operatorname{XOR} 3=4$ that conveniently differs from $000$ at exactly one position. Or are you looking for a formula for the inverse?

Comment: Is there any special reason that you want a recursive function and not a more straightforward?